# Questions on set theory, topological spaces, and continuity.

Tags: general-topology, continuity

(My question would not have fit in the title)

Questions:

a) Let **X** be a euclidean three dimensional space **R$^3$** with the standard Euclidean length and let **Y** $=\{P_1$such that $P_1=(a_1,b_1,c_1)$and $c_1=0\}$. Use the topology for **X** given by the basis of balls $B(P,r)$ with center $P=(a,b,c)$ and radius $r$ for arbitrary $P=(a,b,c)$ and $r\gt0$. Use the subspace topology for **Y**. Define $f:X$ to $Y$ by $f(a,b,c)=(a,b,0)$. Prove that $f$ is continuous.

b) Prove that $f$ as above maps any open subset of **X** to an open subset of **Y**

My Work

a) $f$ projects points onto the $x,y$-plane. Thus the mapping simply eliminates the $z$ coordinate, mapping all $c$ in **X** to zero in **Y**. By definition, a function that maps all elements in **X** to a single point in **Y** is a continuous function. Thus, because $f$ maps all $c$ in **X** to zero in **Y**, it must be a continuous function. Further, assume a ball $B(P,r)=\{\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3$ such that $d(\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3)=r\}$ for which $P=(a,b,\gamma)$ and $f(P)=(a,b,0)$. If $\sqrt{(a-\beta_1)^2+(b-\beta_2)^2+(\gamma-\beta_3)^2}\lt r$ thus being contained by the ball. Surely $d(\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3)$ for $f(P)$ to $\sqrt{(a-\beta_1)^2+(b-\beta_2)^2+0}\lt r$ and is also contained by the ball. Therefore, the function maps an open set to **R$^3$** continuously to an open set in **R$^2$** is a subset of **R$^3$**

b) Under the assumption that the function is continuous, the statement is proven trivially by definition of the continuous function. If $f$ is continuous, then for all $x$ belonging to a set $X$ and all neighborhoods $V$ of $f(x)$, there is a corresponding neighborhood $U$ such that $f(U)$ is a subset of $V$

I feel that these solutions are largely incomplete and inadequate, but I'm not sure how improve upon them. Any additional insight would be much welcomed!

Also, my mathJax kinda sucks, but I tried my best to communicate what I mean. Feel free to edit the question if it helps you think about the question!!

Comment: $f$ doesn't map all elements of $X$ to a single point. You also seem to be confused about the definition of a continuous function...